# UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad - Display options

Tags: ios, keyboard

I need to use the, Name Phone Keyboard type (UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad) but having the number pad appear first when the text field is selected.

I need to input data such as

123 -
657 -
450b -
123a

I always need input a number first, but occasionally either a A / B at the end.

Comment: any luck finding a true solution? I like to prevent one unnessarcy click also

Comment: not yet - haven't tried in iOS 9 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change keyboard type in function of the size of the string:

- Implement delegate UITextFieldDelegate

Then set defaut textfield keyboard;

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
[textField setDelegate:self];
```

Then in the following method, change the keyboard when text size equals 3:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([[textField text] length] > 3)
    {
        [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
        [textField reloadInputViews];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Another solution is to add an accessory view button (you can change of keyboard manually):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeKeyboard) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    textField.inputAccessoryView = button;
}

-(void)changeKeyboard
{
    if([textField keyboardType] == UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad)
    {
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault;
    }
    else
    {
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    }
    [textField reloadInputViews];
}
```

Comment: That is one option, a cleaver one actually... but would rather try and figure out out to get the secondary view to appear first.

Comment: I understand, I think it is not possible because you can't simulate keyboard touch programmatically

Comment: thanks nico. maybe I can set the number pad keyboard - the blank bottom left button to switch to the default keyboard ?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer with a second solution. Using a button on the keyboard to switch keyboard type. But in my mind you can't add a button on the blank button.

Comment: Start with UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad and place a UIButton over the decimal point with a label "ABC".  That button's action changes thekeyboard to UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad and hides the button.

Answer (score 0):

click on the textfield,then go to Hide or show utilities ie View(you will find it at right hand side beside the editor.There you select the third view ie the most right one).
Then you click the attributes inspector.In that you will find a menu called "keyboard" which is set as default,but you can select whichever pad you want.
Hope it works for you.

Comment: I have done this, and thats isnt the issue. I can get this keyboard to appear, but I want the secondary (numbers) view to appear FIRST - not the letters.