# How do i get this specific keyboardType UI with swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am aware of NumberPad, but this particular keyboard (see image) is the keyboard i like to use as default keyboard for a particular textfield. I got it when i set textField.keyboardType = .NamePhonePad

and when i select numbers on the keyboard i get this one

[image: keyboard type]

Comment: What's your question? Using `NamePhonePad` should give you the keyboard in the picture.

Comment: @rmaddy hmm that's what i thought but i gives me the regular keyboard. Only when i click 123 then i see the keyboard as in the picture

Comment: OK, that's the point of the keyboard. Tap ABC and you get the regular keyboard. Tap 123 and you get the number pad. Again, what's your question?

Comment: I like the "123" keyboard UI to be the first to see. Just what you you see when using textField.keyboardType = .Numberpad or .DecimalPad only with the ABC in the left corner. I want to use that particular keyboard UI as i know the input starts with 7 numbers 3 chars 3 numbers again.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671883/uikeyboardtypenamephonepad-display-options